# Can I reference a .NET 3.5 DLL from a Windows Universal app ?

Tags: c#, .net, dll, win-universal-app

I hate to ask such a simple question but I cannot find a quick answer searching around for 20 minutes.

I am trying to share a DLL between Unity3d and Windows Universal App..  But When I try to add Reference from the Universal App I get 'Unable to add a reference to project'

So I am guessing I should looking into PCLs ?

Comment: (I love when people answer their own question within the question.) ... yes, use PCL

Comment: Well I can't use PCL since I need .NET 3.5 (for Unity3d).. So there seems no way to share a DLL between Unity3d/Universal App/.NET 3.5

Comment: Create a second project file an import the CS files.  you will have to manually maintain the references but that's how we did things before PCL.

Comment: Well it turns out there are no completely compatible REST libs (restsharp is 3.5 and not UAP / rest portable is UAP and not 3.5) so I guess I just can't share some things

Comment: That was the fun game we had before.  You should be able to use HttpWebRequest. on hte .Net 3.5 side.  If you make a standard interface you can just inject your own RESTful client wrapper into your client then just map the functions.  Again it sucks... but that is what you are going to have to do.  (either that or just write two independant clients.)

Comment: I know there some clever way to make it work with interfaces or injection or something but I am not that smart.. I'm just going to stick with a lib for sharing me Unity3d (3.5) and my work Dlls (3.5).. and down the road I can look into it again